# Html accesskey with two or three words

Tags: javascript, html

I am using accesskey attribute for button press like `accesskey="a"`

But I want like this: `accesskey="a+b"`

Instead of only "a" I want to use "a" and "b"

How to use more than one word for accesskey in html?

Comment: What is your Question?

Comment: @user9041563, your question is not clear, you mean `accesskey="a"` is one button and `accesskey="b"` is another button ? if you click both button same action want to execute .?

Comment: There is only one button and I want to use combination of words for accesskey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined by [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/editing.html#the-accesskey-attribute), the accesskey can only be set to a single printable character.

If you want multiple keys to trigger the same action, you can make some additional elements and make them hidden using `display:none`, such as...

```
<a href="#" accesskey="a">A link</a>
<a href="#" accesskey="b" style="display:none"></a>
```

The second link is invisible but pressing the accesskey combination for B will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript.

```html
<button onclick="console.log('save')" data-hotkey="Ctrl+S">Save</button>
<button onclick="console.log('print')" data-hotkey="Alt+P">Print</button>
<button onclick="console.log('debug')" data-hotkey="Ctrl+Alt+D">Debug</button>


<script>
  document.addEventListener("keydown", (keyboardEvent) => {
    // KeyboardEvent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent

    /* You can do some checking to end early for efficiency.
    if (!(keyboardEvent.ctrlKey || keyboardEvent.altKey)) {
      return
    }
     */

    [...document.querySelectorAll(`[data-hotkey]`)].forEach(elem => {
      const combineKey = elem.dataset.hotkey.split("+")
      // check
      for (let myKeyStr of combineKey) {
        myKeyStr = myKeyStr.toUpperCase()

        if (myKeyStr.length > 1) {
          if (myKeyStr === "CTRL" && keyboardEvent.ctrlKey) {
            continue
          }
          if (myKeyStr === "ALT" && keyboardEvent.altKey) {
            continue
          }
        }
        if (keyboardEvent.key.toUpperCase() !== myKeyStr) {
          return
        }
      }
      keyboardEvent.preventDefault() // prevent default behavior. For example: Ctrl+S will save (for OS:Windows)
      elem.click()
    })
  })
</script>
```